# Forçar https usando .htaccess em apenas determinado domínio e subdominio

Tags: ssl, https, htaccess

Gostaria de saber como forçar o HTTPS usando o `.htaccess` em apenas determinado dominio/subdominio. O código que utilizo está forçando o https em todos os subdomínios... e um dos meus subdominios não possui SSL, por isso desejo que esse não funcione em https.

Meu `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Já tentei colocar um htacess diferente no meu subdominio, mas não deu certo.

Comment: @DanielOmine nesse tópico que você indicou ele ensina como ativar o https em apenas um dominio, sem afetar os outros. O que preciso é que o https funcione em meusite.com e loja.meusite.com sem afetar os outros.

Comment: O nome correto para o arquivo é: .htaccess e não htacess, poderia checar se seu arquivo está com o nome correto?

Comment: @AllanAndrade Descobri o problema, meu navegador salvou o cache com a configuração do htacess anterior e por alguma razão não estava atualizando com o novo htacess que configurei no subdomínio... depois que limpei o cache funcionou normalmente...

Comment: sobre o link, segue a mesma lógica.. basta entender o que foi feito e aplicar ao seu caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome correto para o arquivo é: `.htaccess`

Usar `mod_rewrite` para forçar HTTPS não é recomendado por questões de segurança. [leia mais em RedirectSSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)

É recomendado que você utilize Virtual Host para isso... pode tentar isso:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName secure.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Se mesmo sabendo disso, ainda quiser utilizar `mod_rewrite`:

1 = Remova o arquivo  `.htaccess`  do site raiz: geralmente /var/www/html

2 = Crie os virtual hosts.

3 = Coloque um `.htaccess` na raiz web de cada virtual host que desejar HTTPS.

Exemplo de  arquivo `.htaccess`: 
    RewriteEngine On
    # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Para outros usuários que demandem sobre a mesma questão, lembrar de checar se o seu webserver está com o módulo REWRITE habilitado, caso não esteja, você pode habilitar com o comando:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá @Allan Andrade. Pelo que entendi esse virtual host é uma configuração no meu servidor, e meu host é super limitado e duvido que me permita fazer tal configuração, agora sobre o mod_rewrite o que preciso é que ele configure um dominio e um subdominio no mesmo htacess para ficar em https, os demais devem ficar em http, como especifiquei na minha pergunta. Eu sei como ativar o https para apenas um dominio, ou para todos, mas não sei como remover os demais dessa condição.

Comment: Estes domínios ficam na mesma pasta? Mesmos arquivos? Mesmo código?